# How to make things opaque using GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I followed [this walkthrough](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Changing_Background_Color_1/) on how to select colors with anti-aliasing, and when I finished, everything that hadn't been deleted was not opaque. Yet the layer was at 100% Opacity. How do I fix this??

I want to get rid of the greenish white
[image: I want to get rid of the greenish white]

I go into color>color to alpha. and select the greenish white color
[image: I go into color>color to alpha. and select the greenish white color]

When I click "ok" the greenish white is gone like i wanted, but the text is opaque, how do I fix this?
[image: When I click "ok" the greenish white is gone like i wanted, but the text is opaque, how do I fix this?]

Comment: Sorry, but this case needs some screenshots, we have no idea what you actually want and what's failed. Explanations with words only are too vague. If you have tried something bizarre, we do not know what it is.

Comment: If you are on 2.10, it is possible that you need to add an alpha-channel first (in 2.8 it was added if not there): Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel. Otherwise, what is not deleted is supposed to stay opaque because deletion is really making things transparent...

Comment: There are some images, sorry it took so long

Comment: "opaque" means not transparent, "100% opacity" means the same. Can you describe what the images are showing - especially what order they are supposed to be in - and what you'd expect to see instead?

Comment: If you are taking about the checkerboard pattern, this isn't opaque, this is an indication of where the image is transparent (technically, this is a background that you see only where the image is transparent), but it isn't part of the image.

Comment: @xenoid It isn't the checkered pattern I'm talking about. It's kinda hard to see, but the text that remains is opaque. You can see the checkered pattern through it.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher The first few pictures: color>color to alplha, then selecting the color I wanted to get rid of. Color selector doesn't do this, since it doesn't get rid of the anti aliasing around the edges of letters. In the last image, the green is all gone like I wanted, but the text is  not opaque

Comment: Your question would benefit from an image that shows an enlarged view of one of the characters, where it is obvious that you are looking for a way to make some partially transparent pixels opaque.

Comment: Text looks quite opaque to me. The edge pixels are partially transparent but this is normal (necessary for the anti-aliasing). If you want to make sure that most of the text is not altered, select the background, `Select>Grow` by one pixel to cover the edge pixels, and apply color-to-alpha. In general background selection should be done wit the fuzzy selector (to avoid selecting subject pixels by mistake) but in your case selecting by color is easier (will include the loops in the letters).

Comment: @DJChipmunk - Welcome to GDSE. I think you are confusing the term opaque with transparent. Opaque means totally solid, not transparent or see through.

Answer (score 1):

Color to alpha has affected also partially in the middle of the letters. I guess you have tried to get rid of the remnants of the green color with the treshold sliders in Color to Alpha dialog. After removing the background you have partially transparent letters like these:

[image]

How to fix:

GIMP has the curves adjustment as well for RGB channels as for Alpha. Apply Colors > Curves > Alpha and adjust the curve. The right adjustment makes the letters visually opaque, saves the partial transparency of the edges (=anti-aliasing) and it doesn't lift up background:

[image]

In my case making the curve steeper did the job. You may need a little S-shaped curve to keep the background invisible.

Answer (score 0):

- Fuzzy select the background with the default threshold. Shift-click inside closed areas ('a','e','o') to add them to the selection. In your very specific case (only two constrasting colors in the image), you also do a color selection and use the background color (so yo udon't have to worry about closed areas)
- *Select>Grow* by one pixel so that the selection extends over the pixels on the edges of the letters (if the image is dirty (JPEG artifacts), you can grow by 2 or 3px)
- *Colors>Color to alpha* and remove the background color. With the selection above, C2A will only apply to edge pixels and leave the core of the letters untouched.